# restore /etc/init.d/rc.local

Tags: 13.04, startup, data-recovery, restore, scripts

I've mistakenly copied the /etc/rc.local over the /etc/init.d/rc.local and I was wondering how can I retore the init.d/rc.local contents?

Is it possible to generate the original file or copy it from somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dpkg' to find out which package is providing a file. In your case you could have used:

```
sudo dpkg -S /etc/init.d/rc.local
```

This would have told you that the file is provided by package `initscripts':

```
$ sudo dpkg -S /etc/init.d/rc.local
initscripts: /etc/init.d/rc.local
```

Then just reinstall that package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall initscripts
```

References:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/dpkg.1.html

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man8/apt-get.8.html

Answer (score 1):

I am running Ubuntu 13.04. Here is a link to a text file copy of my  /etc/init.d/rc.local. If you need any further guidance about how to copy it over, please comment.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58267392/local.txt

Comment: thanks! I've copied it and rebooted and works. Alternatively I discovered scalpel for file recovery.